# Rewrite category wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting, categories

Is it possible to rewrite only one category ?

I have a category "**Photos**" and just for this category.

I just want to rewrite it from `/category/photos` to `/photos`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with WP Rewrite API.
Add this to functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'register_rewrites');
function register_rewrites() {
   add_rewrite_rule('^photos$', 'index.php?category_name=photos','top');
}
```

Remember to reload your rewrite settings: go to Settings -> Permalinks and click on Save button - no changes needed.

Answer (score 0):

The Yoast [SEO plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) has this function build in, I recommend this plugin in general.
[no-category-base-wpml](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/) only does this
If you don't want to install a plugin for this. Around the web there are many tutorials which do this:

- http://thisismyurl.com/6704/remove-category-url-wordpress/
- http://www.webdevtuts.net/php/how-to-remove-category-from-wordpress-url-structure/
- http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-remove-category-from-your-wordpress-url

Too enable this for just one category I would advise the following:

1. create a page called `photos`.
2. create a theme [template page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates) for this photo page
3. In is set up a new [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)* getting the category 'photos'
4. Include the `category.php` file.
5. assign that template to the photo page.

Not tested but should work. Because the page has the correct URL and should include the category. Questions, aks.

*query_posts is bad for performance if you want to do it totally correct use the [`pre_get_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts#answer-50762) filter. It's requires more knowledge.

Comment: Yep, thanks for your tutorials, how can I do for only one category. Without affect others categories ?

Comment: Agian I've red your question too quick. Udate incomming.