# Wordpress rewriting URLs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make a Wordpress rewrite rule and it is the first time I do this. I have got some results, but not the ones that I expected.

In my website, I have a blog with many categories (beauty, travelling, etc.). The URL without rewriting is the next one:

```
http://mywebsite.com/blog/?cat=10 //where 10 is the category of Beauty.
```

I want it like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/blog/beauty
```

This is the rule I wrote:

```
add_rewrite_rule('blog/?$?', 'index.php?cat=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

With this rule, it gets translated to:

```
http://mywebsite.com/category/beauty/
```

I guess I'm really close to the solution but I don't know how to get it.

Thank you so much for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally shouldn't do custom URL rewiting in Wordpress [unless you do it the Wordpress way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528800/rewrite-category-wordpress). Wordpress usually reroutes all requests to index.php and then loads the proper content based on the url. Custom rules might interupt this process and cause no content to load at all.

The categories, by default, should appear like `http://mywebsite.com/blog/category/{{your-slug}}/`. If you want the categories to appear without the `/category/` in from of them, you could look into one of the various SEO plugins like YOAST that support this feature. You should be able to use any category slug text you want simply by changing the field in `posts > categories`.

**EDIT**

In my previous answer I assumed Wordpress was installed at `http://mywebsite.com/blog/`. If the Wordpress site url is `http://mywebsite.com/`, you can use parent-child categories to accomplish a url like this: `http://mywebsite.com/category/blog/{{your-slug}}/`. Make `blog` a category and the desired category a [child category](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-categories-and-subcategories-to-wordpress/) of `blog`.

In order to remove the leading `category` you would use a custom permalink structure in `settings > permalinks`:

Set Custom Structure: /%postname%/

Set Category base: .

Comment: Including or not "/category/" in the URL is optional. The main problem is that  "/blog/" is not appearing.

Comment: Where is the homepage of your Wordpress site? Is it `http://mywebsite.com/` or `http://mywebsite.com/blog`? I assumed you installed Wordpress in a subdirectory.

Comment: Oh, okay, I edited my answer to recommend parent-child categories :)